# Can I set environment variables globally in settings.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jfrog-xray

These aren't launch settings, I want these environment variables set when vscode is opened

I'm trying to work with this extension which seems to have no support for `settings.json` for some reason, but does support reading values from env vars: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JFrog.jfrog-vscode-extension#extension-settings

It's not ideal to work with, I am wondering if I can store the env vars it wants in my global `settings.json` instead of having to put them in my bashrc or something- want to keep the config in settings.json because that's how literally every other extension is configured.

Comment: with the env variable `JFROG_IDE_STORE_CONNECTION` you can store the connection details by VSC

Comment: JFROG_IDE_STORE_CONNECTION requires you to use env vars- at least initially. Also, its not clear to me where its storing it- its not storing it in settings.json. This is weird, I have to set env vars for the initial config? That should be a UI option OR I should be able to store them in settings.json

Comment: maybe it modifies a file in the extension directory, just like needed to detect you upgraded an extension